# Swing UIManager.getColor() keys

Tags: java, swing, colors, uimanager

Is there a list somewhere of the `UIManager.getColor()` keys for Swing? I can't seem to find it online, just occasional references to strings like `"Panel.background"` and `"Table.selectionBackground"`.

Comment: I found a handy Java Web Start App that should help: http://tips4java.wordpress.com/2008/10/09/uimanager-defaults/

Answer (score 7):

I don't think there is a defined standard set of keys. But you could try this bit of code to list the ones currently available in alphabetical order:

```
List<String> colors = new ArrayList<String>();
for (Map.Entry<Object, Object> entry : UIManager.getDefaults().entrySet()) {
    if (entry.getValue() instanceof Color) {
        colors.add((String) entry.getKey()); // all the keys are strings
    }
}
Collections.sort(colors);
for (String name : colors)
    System.out.println(name);
```

This produces a list too long to reproduce here.

Comment: Currently (jdk1.8.0_45), for `systemLookAndFeelClassName = com.sun.java.swing.plaf.windows.WindowsLookAndFeel`, the classes are not `java.awt.Color`, but `com.sun.java.swing.plaf.windows.DesktopProperty`, failing the instanceof check unfortunately.

Answer (score 4):

@mmyers got me inspired. Here's a short program to list the UIManager defaults in a sortable table.

```
package com.example.test.gui;

import java.awt.Color;
import java.awt.Component;
import java.util.Map;

import javax.swing.JFrame;
import javax.swing.JLabel;
import javax.swing.JScrollPane;
import javax.swing.JTable;
import javax.swing.UIManager;
import javax.swing.table.DefaultTableCellRenderer;

import ca.odell.glazedlists.BasicEventList;
import ca.odell.glazedlists.EventList;
import ca.odell.glazedlists.GlazedLists;
import ca.odell.glazedlists.SortedList;
import ca.odell.glazedlists.gui.AbstractTableComparatorChooser;
import ca.odell.glazedlists.gui.TableFormat;
import ca.odell.glazedlists.swing.EventTableModel;
import ca.odell.glazedlists.swing.TableComparatorChooser;

public class UIManagerDefaultsViewer {

    public static class UIEntry
    {
        final private String key;
        final private Object value;

        UIEntry(Map.Entry<Object,Object> e)
        {
            this.key = e.getKey().toString();
            this.value = e.getValue(); 
        }

        public String getKey() {
            return key;
        }
        public Object getValue() {
            return value;
        }
        public Class getValueClass() {
            if (value == null)
                return null; // ?!?!?!
            return value.getClass();
        }
        public String getClassName() {
            // doesn't handle arrays properly
            if (value == null)
                return "";

            return value.getClass().getName();
        }
    }   

    public static class UIEntryRenderer extends DefaultTableCellRenderer
    {
        Color[] defaults = new Color[4];
        public UIEntryRenderer()
        {
            super();
            defaults[0] = UIManager.getColor("Table.background");
            defaults[1] = UIManager.getColor("Table.selectionBackground");
            defaults[2] = UIManager.getColor("Table.foreground");
            defaults[3] = UIManager.getColor("Table.selectionForeground");
        }

        public void setDefaultColors(Component cell, boolean isSelected)
        {
            cell.setBackground(defaults[isSelected ? 1 : 0]);
            cell.setForeground(defaults[isSelected ? 3 : 2]);
        }

        @Override
        public Component getTableCellRendererComponent(JTable table, Object value,
                boolean isSelected, boolean hasFocus, int row, int column)
        {
            Component cell = super.getTableCellRendererComponent(table, value,
                    isSelected, hasFocus, row, column);
            if (table.convertColumnIndexToModel(column) == 1) // the value column
            {
                final EventTableModel<UIEntry> tableModel = 
                    (EventTableModel<UIEntry>) table.getModel();
                UIEntry e = tableModel.getElementAt(row);
                JLabel l = (JLabel)cell;


                if (value instanceof Color)
                {
                    Color c = (Color)value;
                    cell.setBackground(c);
                    cell.setForeground(
                            c.getRed()+c.getGreen()+c.getBlue() >= 128*3
                            ? Color.black : Color.white);
                    // choose either black or white depending on brightness

                    l.setText(String.format("Color 0x%08x (%d,%d,%d alpha=%d)",
                        c.getRGB(), c.getRed(), c.getGreen(), c.getBlue(), c.getAlpha()));
                    return cell;
                }
                else if (e.getKey().endsWith("ont"))
                    // possible font, not always ".font"
                {
                    // fonts are weird, for some reason the value returned
                    // in the entry set of UIManager.getDefaults()
                    // is not the same type as the value "v" below                  
                    Object v = UIManager.get(e.getKey());
                    if (v instanceof javax.swing.plaf.FontUIResource)
                    {
                        javax.swing.plaf.FontUIResource font = 
                            (javax.swing.plaf.FontUIResource)v;
                        l.setText("Font "+font.getFontName()+" "+font.getSize());
                    }
                }
            }

            setDefaultColors(cell, isSelected);

            return cell;
        }
    }   

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        final EventList<UIEntry> uiEntryList = 
            GlazedLists.threadSafeList(new BasicEventList<UIEntry>());

        for (Map.Entry<Object,Object> key : UIManager.getDefaults().entrySet())
        {
            uiEntryList.add(new UIEntry(key));
        }

        final SortedList<UIEntry> sortedUIEntryList = new SortedList<UIEntry>(uiEntryList, null);

        // build a JTable
        String[] propertyNames = new String[] {"key","value","className"};
        String[] columnLabels = new String[] {"Key", "Value", "Class"};
        TableFormat<UIEntry> tf = GlazedLists.tableFormat(UIEntry.class, propertyNames, columnLabels);
        EventTableModel<UIEntry> etm = new EventTableModel<UIEntry>(sortedUIEntryList, tf);

        JTable t = new JTable(etm);
        TableComparatorChooser<UIEntry> tcc = TableComparatorChooser.install(t, 
                sortedUIEntryList, AbstractTableComparatorChooser.SINGLE_COLUMN,
                tf);
        sortedUIEntryList.setComparator(tcc.getComparatorsForColumn(0).get(0));
        // default to sort by the key

        t.setDefaultRenderer(Object.class, new UIEntryRenderer());        

        JFrame f = new JFrame("UI Manager Defaults Viewer");
        // show the frame
        f.add(new JScrollPane(t));
        f.pack();
        f.setLocationRelativeTo(null);
        f.setDefaultCloseOperation(JFrame.EXIT_ON_CLOSE);
        f.setVisible(true);     
    }

}
```

Comment: In the NetBeans GUI builder, when you edit a color you can pick from a JList with all of these listed (without the actual color values). That's actually where I got the idea that it might be possible to list them. A table is much nicer, though.

Answer (score 3):

This program is the best I've seen for visualizing the UIManager values (e.g. Fonts, Colors, Borders): http://tips4java.wordpress.com/2008/10/09/uimanager-defaults/

It lacks search, but it can filter by component or value type, which is pretty great.

Answer (score 0):

They are kind of Look and Feel implementation dependent. Look in `BasicLookAndFeel.java` for the basic keys. Don't expect all PL&F to behave the same, or even remain the same between versions.